# creating an authenticated user in rails console is showing contradicting data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-console

I'm reviewing Hartl's Rails Tutorial and while I'm able to successfully create a user in the console, I am confused by the current feedback:

```
2.0.0-p247 :014 > user.update_attributes name: "Ryan Waits", email: "ryan.waits@gmail.com"
(0.3ms)  begin transaction
User Exists (0.3ms)  # commented out
=> true 
2.0.0-p247 :015 > user
=> #<User id: 2, name: nil, email: nil, # commented out
2.0.0-p247 :016 > user.name
=> "Ryan Waits"
```

It creates the user as it should, but why do I need to specifically call on user.name or user.email in order to show their values...anyone have an idea?

user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 before_save { self.email == email.downcase }
 attr_accessor :name, :email

 validates :name, presence: true
 VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
 validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                        uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false}

 has_secure_password
 validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 def index
 @user = User.all
end

 def new

 end

 def show
  @user = User.find params[:id]
 end
end
```

Besides the console showing a user has been created, I don't have any users in the database when trying to display them on either the index or show views.

index error:

*undefined method `email' for #*

index view:

```
<%= @user.name %>
<%= @user.email %>
```

Comment: Are you in the rails console or ruby console? Only asking because of this:
2.0.0-p247 :014 >

Looks like you are in the ruby directory.

Comment: @creativereason I am in the rails console...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

irb just has the cached version of the object in memory.  what does `user.reload` instead of `user` show you

Comment: user.reload gives me the same output: => #<User id: 2, name: nil, email: nil, created_at: "2013-10-29 18:26:26", updated_at: "2013-10-29 18:26:26", password_digest: "$2a$10$ZHeDEWw/.v.WjtAt88Bz8O5Mpxs6mBTkSd4EwGLQDFEu...">

Comment: afaik, irb just calls `#inspect` on the object by default